# How to find port allocation? Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: ubuntu, port

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: outline
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    volumes:
      - ./data/minio_root:/minio_root:z
      - ./data/certs:/root/.minio/certs:z
    command: "minio server /minio_root"
    env_file: ./env.minio
    restart: always
  outline:
    image: outlinewiki/outline:latest
    command: sh -c "yarn sequelize:migrate --env production-ssl-disabled && yarn start"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:pass@postgres:5432/outline
      - DATABASE_URL_TEST=postgres://user:pass@postgres:5432/outline-test
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    env_file:
      - ./env.outline
      - ./env.slack
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - minio
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 4443:443
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:z
      - ./data/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/:z
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - outline
```

I am running up -d

```
docker-compose up -d
WARNING: Found orphan containers (outline_webserver_1, outline_certbot_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating outline_postgres_1 ... done
Creating outline_redis_1    ... done
Creating outline_minio_1    ... done
Creating outline_outline_1  ... done
Creating outline_nginx_1    ... 
Creating outline_nginx_1    ... error

ERROR: for outline_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint outline_nginx_1 (04142433bde69c0122c47ea24dac5f61018cf3f108ea2e7bd3ab079b18d0ad98): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated
```

Ok,let's check now

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:80 shows nothing
```

Then

```
ss -lptn 'sport = :80'
State                Recv-Q                Send-Q                               Local Address:Port                               Peer Address:Port               Process
```

The same.

What could cause this error?

Comment: I do not see a `sudo` in your `docker-compose` command. I believe ordinary user can not use ports below 1024. That is a security measure. You need to be root to allocate port lower than 1024. What does `netstat` say about port 80?

Comment: Try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

Comment: Maybe the port is being used in a different namespace which cannot be displayed by `ss`, `nestat`, `lsof`. Are you running other images on the same Linux kernel (docker images, WSL2 distributions...)? Try to check them maybe they use the same network namespace (default in WSL2) and other image occupies the port 80.

Comment: Yes,it was in Dokcer network,fixed that.

Comment: Here is the answer, in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46176584/docker-bind-for-0-0-0-04000-failed-port-is-already-allocated

Comment: If you are running DDEV, the fix for me was to run `ddev poweroff; ddev config; ddev start`. I also had another time with WSL2 where restarting my computer fixed it.